# Cannot get response while using jQuery.get Ajax function

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have python script on server. It displays simple html page. It opens fine in browser. I try to get this page using ajax. But the response seems to be timed out (just assuming...) and no response received. Chrome shows that the status of this request is **canceled**. Why?

```
$.get("MYURL",function(data,status){
                    alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
                  });
```

[image]
AND
[image]
PS. The html which request using ajax is stored at localhost. If server blocks my ajax requests then it prevents **XSS** ?

UPDATE:
Python script

```
#!/usr/bin/python
print "Content-type: text/html"
print
print "<html><head><title>test.py</title></head><body><h1>Hello, World!</h1></body>"
print
```

UPDATE2:
Chrome console:
**XMLHttpRequest cannot load `http://MYSERVER/hello.py`. Origin `http://localhost` is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.**

Comment: Where are you accessing the HTML from? File system (`file://`)? The server? Who's serving the ajax? Where is it?

Comment: I have xampp on localhost and HTML file which requests using ajax. I have python script on internet server. The script returns html page.

Comment: In the network tab of chrome, you are only showing the last line. Show us more lines. There's probably an `OPTIONS` request before that `GET`. You are probably are unable to make cross-domain (CORS) requests to your "internet server".

Comment: Javacsript does not have access to the online script, as it has a same origin policy, meaning it can only do requests to the same domain, unless it's JSONP or CORS is enabled.

Comment: How to modify my ajax request so it can make and receive response (using CORS or JSONP) ?